# How simulate a click on physical android menu button?

Tags: android, button, automation, appium

I'm doing automation on real Android device with Appium and Ruby.
I want to know if it's possible to simulate a click on the physical menu button (the one which open settings on several app) ?

Comment: like when you press back button ?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple. Just call `openOptionsMenu()` in the activity.